# ELI5: What is a macro name?

Tags: c++, header-files

I'm following [this tutorial](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Creating_a_new_project) about the basics of Code::Blocks projects. To use multiple files in a project, you need a header file. [This section](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Creating_a_new_project#Adding_a_pre-existing_file) gives the source code for the most basic of header files, but gives no explanation.

```
#ifndef HELLO_H_INCLUDED
#define HELLO_H_INCLUDED

void hello();

#endif // HELLO_H_INCLUDED
```

I got curious about the significance of `HELLO_H_INCLUDED`. I changed it to various names, and the project parsed and ran properly regardless of what I named it.

However, if you delete `HELLO_H_INCLUDED` entirely, it an error arises saying `no macro name given in #ifndef directive`.

So, explain to me like I'm five years old: What is a macro name, what does it do, and why is it required?

Comment: What you have is known as an include guard. That's the term to look for. Removing the identifier part of it is simply wrong because `#ifndef` (shorthand for `#if not defined`) needs a name in order to check whether it's not defined.

Comment: Maybe not the best dupe to find, but there are many explanations what these so called _header or include guards_ are doing, and why they are useful. Even [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) explains it